# Are there certain Pokemon that are gender bound?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I've heard rumors from a friend who claimed it was true, that all Torchics received during the event would be of only the male type.

Does this same scenario hold true for any other Pokemon in X Y?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most stats of event Pokemon are pre-determined, set by the event itself. So, all event Torchics are indeed male. Depending on the event, Nature can be preset although it wasn't the case with the Torchic event.

As for other Pokemon, we cannot know for sure as no event Pokemon have been released. As for wild Pokemon, of the new ones released in X/Y, only the Flabebe line has a mono-gender distribution, being 100% female.

Comment: It's worth noting that on top of what you've said, some Pokemon's gender distributions in the wild are skewed. For example, you're more likely to run into male Eevee than female (the distribution being about 75/25% if I recall correctly)

Comment: Actually, it's 87.5% male and vice-versa for other species. The starters themselves are also 87.5% male. I didn't mention these skewed gender distributions as there are no new X/Y Pokemon with skewed gender distributions other than the starters.